# Mi vituralbox no se conecta a internet

Tags: virtualbox, virtualización

como se puede ver en el titulo mi maquina virtual no se conecta al internet, la cosa es que he buscado bastante en internet y siempre dice el mismo método de cambiar a "adaptador puente" y lo entiendo, ya hice una maquina así y me termino solucionando el problema en su día, lo que pasa es que con esta maquina no me pasa lo mismo, mas bien la unica forma que tengo de tener internet es con el NAT pero tambien quiero que la maquina este conectada a la red local.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como esta configurada, también he cambiado al modo promiscuo "permitir vms" y tampoco funciona, entonces no se como hacer para tener conexión a internet, por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Asegurate que las interfaz este recibiendo una ip válida, con el comando ifconfig, si no es asi tienes que levantar la interfaz manualmente

Comment: recibe una ip IPv4 e IPv6, incluso si se conecta al wifi y todo el problema es que no tiene acceso a internet

Answer (score 0):

Creo si la configuras como "NAT" te funcionará.

Es la configuración que yo tengo y accede a internet. Los paquetes IP pasan por un router virtual del ordenador anfitrion y salen a internet como salgan a través del propio ordenador.

Comment: Si, se que si funciona, pero lo que yo busco no es solo que se conecte a internet, si no que este conectada a internet y que pueda conectarse a al red local del wifi